# Find a strictly increasing function $ f$ with $ f'(1)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

> Find a strictly increasing function $ f$ with $ f'(1)=0$.

I've found the function $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}−x^2+x$

But I don't know how to prove that the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: "I don't know how to prove that the function..." What function is "that?" You have to pick a function first. It's not true for all functions.

Comment: Show $f' \ge 0$

Comment: note that $f(x)=\frac 1 3 ((x-1)^3+1) $

Comment: Rather than trying to prove that a particular function is strictly increasing, try to find a function for which it's easy to prove that it's increasing.

Answer (score 6):

What about $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=(x-1)^3$?